# GSABR model vs SABR model

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-volatility, local-volatility, volatility-smile, sabr-model

I've read about the SABR model for pricing options, however I am told there is a variant called GSABR. Does anyone know how this model differs from the original SABR model?. Any papers would be really useful.

Thanks!